# JavaFX - Removing a Tab from a TabPane does not trigger the setOnClosed() callback

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I would like to execute code in the `setOnClosed` callback of a JavaFX Tab.
However, when I remove the Tab from the TabPane:

```
TabPane rootTabPane;
rootTabPane.getTabs().remove(tab1);
```

In the tab's controller, the callback is never executed:

```
tab1.setOnClosed(event -> timerStop());
```

When the tab is closed by a mouse click, the callback is run but not when the tab is removed in the code.

How can I close a tab in my code so that the callback is called? I have many tabs with very different behaviors and would like a generic method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TAB_CLOSED` event is only triggered if the tab is closed as result of user interaction. Programmatically removing the `Tab` does not trigger this event, but nothing prevents you from firing it yourself:

```
public static void removeTabWithEvent(Tab tab) {
    tab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(tab);
    Event closedEvent = new Event(tab, tab, Tab.CLOSED_EVENT);
    Event.fireEvent(tab, closedEvent);
}
```

Comment: `tab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(tab);` I am guessing this is a mistake and should be `rootTabPane.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(tab);`

Comment: @Sedrick No: A `Tab` allows you to retrieve the `TabPane` it's displayed in and this method just removes the tab from the `TabPane` where it's displayed. Sure you could pass the `TabPane` as seperate parameter, but this is not necessary and this way you may actually prevent some errors, if you're working with multiple `TabPane`s... BTW: `rootTabPane` is the `TabPane` and does not contain a `getTabPane` method.

Comment: I overlooked `getTabPane()`.

Comment: Thank you @fabian! This is exactly what I was hoping for.